# Issues with SQL JOIN failing

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join

I have the following `JOIN` I am attempting to create.

```
SELECT rating_draft_result.COUNT(id), rating_draft_result.user_id, rating_draft_result.result 
FROM rating_draft_result
INNER JOIN users ON
rating_draft_result.user_id, rating_draft_result.result = users.id
```

I am trying to `COUNT` the total `id`'s of the rating_draft_result table and then also `SELECT` the user_id and result from that table. Then I am trying to match the user_id and result from the rating_draft_result table to the user's id column. Then I want to get the username from the user's table where the id matches, but I can't figure that part out and I am getting an error anyways with the following code.

I get the following error..

> Survey SELECT total count prepare() failed: You have an error in your
>   SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server
>   version for the right syntax to use near '.id' at line 4

My database tables look like this...

```
users
CREATE TABLE `users` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `firstname` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `lastname` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `email` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `phone_number` varchar(15) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `username` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `password` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `salt` varchar(32) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `joined` datetime NOT NULL,
 `group` int(11) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=105 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci

rating_draft_result
CREATE TABLE `rating_draft_result` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `result` int(11) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=28 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

What am I doing wrong in my query?

DESIRED OUTPUT:

users
    CREATE TABLE `users` (
     ``` id``firstname``lastname``email``phone_number``username``password``salt``joined ``` `group`

```
 1   Jack   Johnson  jack@email.com  2222  jackusername  ffd  fdddfd  today  1
 10   Tom   Thompson  fdfdfddf@fef.com 5555  Tomusername


rating_draft_result
     `id` `user_id` `result`
      20    1         10
```

I want to be able to match the rating_draft_result's `user_id` and `result` with the user table's id field.

So I want to get the jackusername and tomusername fields.

Comment: @everyone How do you know he doesn't also want to use the `result` column as part of the join condition?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I do want to join that as well.

Comment: Can you show us a sample output which you want to get from your query?

Comment: I want this to work `rating_draft_result.user_id = users.id` and then to get the username from the users table where users.id matches the rating_draft_result.user_id. I hope that helps.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I updated my question to show what I am trying to get... This does not count for the count I am trying to get though.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen here is the fiddle. I created it with my initial query. However, with my query on my site I get 1 to show up. http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/89be1/1 ... I am just trying to get the usernames for the `rating_draft_result` query to show up for both the `user_id` and `result` usernames. Then count the amount of id's the `rating_draft_result' has.

Answer (score 2):

Check `JOIN` condition

```
SELECT rating_draft_result.user_id, rating_draft_result.result, COUNT(*)
FROM rating_draft_result
INNER JOIN users
  ON rating_draft_result.user_id = users.id
GROUP BY rating_draft_result.user_id, rating_draft_result.result;
```

You have

> ON rating_draft_result.user_id, **rating_draft_result.result** = users.id

Comment: @Ralph Try with group by

Comment: I'm not wanting to count the total records. Only the id from the rating_draft_result table. I don't get an errors, but the count shows 100 when it needs to be two

Comment: @Ralph First learn how to ask question. I can't see your data, so as Tim Biegeleisen said  "all answers are speculative"

Comment: It clearly shows in my question I am attempting to `COUNT` the number of id's IN the  rating_draft_result table NOT ALL of the records. Learn how to read.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in your `JOIN ON` clause. You need to change it like

```
INNER JOIN users ON
rating_draft_result.user_id = users.id
```

(OR) If you want to have both the conditions then use a `AND` operator like

```
FROM rating_draft_result
INNER JOIN users ON
rating_draft_result.user_id = users.id
AND rating_draft_result.result = users.id
```

Change your entire query to be like below

```
SELECT COUNT(rating_draft_result.id), 
rating_draft_result.user_id, 
rating_draft_result.result 
FROM rating_draft_result
INNER JOIN users ON
rating_draft_result.user_id = users.id
AND rating_draft_result.result = users.id;
```

Comment: I can't have multiple rating_draft_result clauses? How can I have both the user_id and result = `users.id`?

Comment: @Ralph, use a AND / OR condition. see edit in answer if that helps.

Comment: I now get this when I change it... `Survey SELECT total count prepare() failed: FUNCTION rating_draft_result.COUNT does not exist. Check the 'Function Name Parsing and Resolution' section in the Reference Manual` How can I make the `COUNT` work like I am trying to get it to.

Comment: When I do this ... `SELECT COUNT(rating_draft_result.id)` I get the wrong  count total.

Comment: @Ralph You need to show us your desired output.  Until you do this, all answers are going to be speculative.

Comment: @Rahul it is still only showing 1. Do I need the result of this to be in a loop? Before I added onto this query, this was working just great and I didn't have it in a loop.

Comment: @Rahul here is the fiddle. I created it with my initial query. However, with my query on my site I get 1 to show up. http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/89be1/1 ... I am just trying to get the usernames for the `rating_draft_result` query to show up for both the `user_id` and `result` usernames. Then count the amount of id's the `rating_draft_result' has.